# POST 400 bad request - contact form (react, nodemailer, axios)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, nodemailer

I tried to do contact form using nodemailer and axios. Unfortunately I am getting error 'POST "localhost:3000/api/form' 400 bad request'. Please take a look at code below.

Screenshot of problem. [click me to see >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9uzd.jpg)

Below is the file with form. I wanna send request from here.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      MARKA: "",
      MODEL: "",
      ROCZNIK: "",
      POJEMNOŚĆ: "",
      ADRES: "",
      IMIĘ: "",
      TELEFON: "",
      EMAIL: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { MARKA, MODEL, ROCZNIK, POJEMNOŚĆ, ADRES, IMIĘ, TELEFON, EMAIL} = this.state;

    axios.post('/api/form', {
      MARKA, MODEL, ROCZNIK, POJEMNOŚĆ, ADRES, IMIĘ, TELEFON, EMAIL
    });
  }
```

Below is file where I wanna use form values from request and send email.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    const htmlEmail = `
    <h3>Pan/Pani ${req.body.IMIĘ} chce wycenić:</h3><br />
    <ul>
      <li>Marka: ${req.body.MARKA}</li>
      <li>Model: ${req.body.MODEL}</li>
      <li>Rocznik: ${req.body.ROCZNIK}</li>
      <li>Pojemność: ${req.body.ROCZNIK}</li>
    </ul><br />
    <h5>Dane kontaktowe oraz adres:</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>Numer telefonu: ${req.body.TELEFON}</li>
      <li>Adres e-mail: ${req.body.EMAIL}</li>
      <li>Lokalizacja: ${req.body.ADRES}</li>
    </ul>
  `;

  let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "deivuss331@gmail.com",
      pass: "fuckingpasswd"
    }
  });

  const message = {
    from: "deivuss331@gmail.com",
    to: "deivuss331@gmail.com",
    subject: "AUTOPLUS GORLICE - Wniosek o wycenę pojazdu",
    html: htmlEmail
  };

  transport.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Wysłano');
  });
  })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("worksss");
});
``
```

Comment: Can you up full code of your server? I can't see any problem with above code

Comment: @TienDuong I did it.